# Navigation through TabbarController And NavigationController. How?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i have storyboard file like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUjiw.png)

when user is loggedin i make segue with:

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let initialVC: UITabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loggedin") as! UITabBarController
 self.present(initialVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and automaticly open viewcontroller with identifier "selectsaloon", but sometimes depending on the condition I need to go to viewcontroller with identifier "searchparams". help me find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Make navigation on viewdidload for  `selectsaloon` when condition occuer

```
    if (condition) {
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let initialVC: UIVieWController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchparams") as! UIViewController
     self.navigationController.push(initialVC, animated: true)
 }
```